# Odd results with typeof and undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please explain this to me, why am I getting `0` instead of `5`?

Inside HTML file :

```
<script>
    var x = 5;
</script>
<div id="dv"></div>
```

Inside JS file :

```
$(function () {
  if(typeof x == 'undefined') {
    var x = 0;
    $("#dv").html(x);
  } else if (x == 5) {
    $("#dv").html(x);
  }
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where do you load the js file? Before or after the script tag where you assing `x`?

Comment: It is hoisting `var x` inside the IIFE

Comment: @Ozan before, of course... the `x = 5` is loaded before

Comment: You are creating a local `x` in your code, which will overwrite the global one. Even though the `var x = 0` is mentioned after the `if` clause, `x` is still redeclared locally before the `if` (this is called hoisting). Then it will be undefined, in which case it will be defined to `0`

Comment: [Docs on hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: @gurvinder372 you mean because it's inside the `$(function () {...` ?

Comment: Yes, javascript is a function scoped language and hoists variable declarations to the top of that scope

Comment: Omg... thanks guys... Didn't know that. But would it be fine if I'll remove the `var` inside the invoking function then? So to say: `if(typeof x == undefined) { x = 0; ... }` Correct?  Thanks, @devnull69

Comment: No because then your trying to set `0` to an undefined varaible. Like I said in my answer. What exactly are you trying to stop here? if you script runs on ready then `x` should always be defined in your example

Comment: @Liam yes, I am... but what's wrong with that? I mean if I detect that the variable isn't defined, I want to set it to `0`. That's the way I want it. Is this not "right" in terms of good coding or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of [variable hoisting in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) your script is **ran** as though it is:

```
$(function () {
  var x;
  if(typeof x == 'undefined') {
    x = 0;
    $("#dv").html(x);
  } else if (x == 5) {
    $("#dv").html(x);
  }
});
```

So `x` never equals `undefined` so it never sets it to `0`. Note the variable `x` in your function is a different variable to the variable `x` in the page. This is because the variable in the script is [closed over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) into the function scope.

---

If I'm understanding your problem correct I would do it this way:

```
<body data-x="5">
...
<div id="dv"></div>
```

---

```
$(function () {
  var x;
  if(typeof $('body').data('x') !== 'undefined') {

    $("#dv").html($('body').data('x'));
  } else {
    $("#dv").html(0);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. So what is the workaround of this - or this simply mean I won't be able to use the `x` of the `x = 5` inside of the invoking function? Because if I remove `var` from the invoking function, it does working

Comment: TBH what's your actual issue here? why would x not be defined? This whole thing is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: hehe :) Well, I'm trying to manipulate the results upon the dynamic variable I'm getting. And then I want to check for the results. So, if I'm getting the `x = undefined`, I want to define it to `0`, if it's defined on the page as `x = 1`, I want to use `if else` statement to output some specific results. If it's `x = 2` exactly as with `x = 1`, but different output

Comment: but obviously the whole point here is to code right, in correct manner so to say :) So I'm not sure now, if I'm removing the `var` from the "scoped" invoked function, would I be doing right coding?

Comment: Because as far as I got it now, without the `var` inside the invoking fuction, it should look for outside for it, right? so it should be correct. Or I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: But if the var exists outside of it, why are you checking for undefined at all? It's **never** going to be undefined?!

Comment: It will, if the variable doesn't exist in the page file :) Variable is dynamic... It will be there only in some circumstances